# ошибка Android resource linking failed

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По книге  Head First Android делаю программу, выдает ошибку, при нажатии на ошибку показывает на обьект Spinner в activity_find_beer.xml . из названия ошибки думаю что причина в неправильно указанной ссылке.
Прошу направить на правильный путь

*Заранее спасибо за ответы!*

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.beeradviser2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".FindBeerActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_find_beer.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:entires="@array/beer_colors"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/find_beer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/color"
        android:layout_below="@+id/color"
        android:text="@string/find_beer"
        android:onClick="onClickFindBeer"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/brands"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/find_beer"
        android:layout_below="@id/find_beer"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/brands" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
   <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Beer Adviser2</string>
    <string-array name="beer_colors">
        <item>light</item>
        <item>amber</item>
        <item>brown</item>
        <item>dark</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="find_beer">Find Beer!</string>
    <string name="brands" />
</resources>
```

FindBeerActivity.java

```
    package com.example.beeradviser2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FindBeerActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_beer);
    }
    public void onClickFindBeer(View view) {
        TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
        Spinner color = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color);
        String beerType = String.valueOf(color.getSelectedItem());
        brands.setText(beerType);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: учту, спасибо. поправил, сейчас вроде норм стало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опечатка в

`android:entires="@array/beer_colors"`

Должно быть `entries`.